# I just need javascript-playwright code for retrieving a verification code my web app will be sending to a twilio account phone number

Tags: twilio

I just need javascript-playwright code for retrieving a verification code my web app will be sending to a twilio account phone number retrieve a verification code sent to a twilio account number.

sadsdsad
sdsadsadsad
sdsadsadsadsadsad
asdsadsadasdasd

Comment: Can you please add more details in this question? Why would you like to receive the verification code with a Twilio number? Usually Twilio numbers send codes. Also, do you already know [Twilio Verify](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api) which will make this scenario very easy.